# Curve fitting using FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

In general I want to know how to use FFT to do curve fitting.  If I could understand the following example I would be happy:

In Matlab I do

Y=[10.6534
    9.6646
    8.7137
    8.2863
    8.2863
    8.7137
    9.0000
    9.5726
   11.0000
   12.7137
   13.4274
   13.2863
   13.0000
   12.7137
   12.5726
   13.5726
   15.7137
   17.4274
   18.0000
   18.0000
   17.4274
   15.7137
   14.0297
   12.4345];

In answer to another question Emre wrote:

You can dispatch this problem with one line of MATLAB, f=fit(t',Y,'fourier8'), the result of which is:

f =

General model Fourier8:
 f(x) = 
           a0 + a1*cos(x*w) + b1*sin(x*w) + 
           a2*cos(2*x*w) + b2*sin(2*x*w) + a3*cos(3*x*w) + b3*sin(3*x*w) + 
           a4*cos(4*x*w) + b4*sin(4*x*w) + a5*cos(5*x*w) + b5*sin(5*x*w) + 
           a6*cos(6*x*w) + b6*sin(6*x*w) + a7*cos(7*x*w) + b7*sin(7*x*w) + 
           a8*cos(8*x*w) + b8*sin(8*x*w)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a0 =       4.889  (-4.318, 14.09)
   a1 =      -13.85  (-26.55, -1.152)
   b1 =       6.884  (-5.952, 19.72)
   a2 =      -2.135  (-2.839, -1.431)
   b2 =          13  (-2.486, 28.48)
   a3 =       6.205  (-2.355, 14.76)
   b3 =        8.53  (0.1128, 16.95)
   a4 =       6.537  (-2.725, 15.8)
   b4 =       3.137  (2.424, 3.851)
   a5 =       5.048  (0.8798, 9.216)
   b5 =      -1.603  (-6.124, 2.918)
   a6 =        1.68  (1.289, 2.071)
   b6 =      -2.345  (-5.843, 1.153)
   a7 =      -0.158  (-1.539, 1.223)
   b7 =      -1.358  (-2.395, -0.3211)
   a8 =     -0.5341  (-1.093, 0.02453)
   b8 =     -0.3162  (-0.6587, 0.02635)
   w =      0.1994  (0.19, 0.2087)

But I want to know how to do this notwithstanding Matlab.  How do I go from this

> > fft(Y)

ans =

```
1.0e+02 *

3.0392
```

-0.1112 + 0.4621i
   -0.1005 + 0.1813i
   -0.0228 - 0.0925i
    0.0069 + 0.0316i
    0.0031 - 0.0007i
    0.0034 - 0.0179i
   -0.0036 + 0.0147i
   -0.0055 + 0.0015i
   -0.0041 - 0.0017i
   -0.0033 - 0.0022i
   -0.0021 - 0.0024i
   -0.0027
   -0.0021 + 0.0024i
   -0.0033 + 0.0022i
   -0.0041 + 0.0017i
   -0.0055 - 0.0015i
   -0.0036 - 0.0147i
    0.0034 + 0.0179i
    0.0031 + 0.0007i
    0.0069 - 0.0316i
   -0.0228 + 0.0925i
   -0.1005 - 0.1813i
   -0.1112 - 0.4621i

To the above result produced by Matlab's "fit" function?  I apologize if the answer should be obvious.